# Issue with translation to different language using Jquery i18n

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, encoding, jquery-globalization

I am developing the mobile app with multilanguage support using phonegap and jquery.I am using Jquery i18n for multi language support.

Followed the example shown in the [site](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/).

I am able to pick the right file, but it shows me with the special characters.
For example:If the text is  "Olá World" it displays "Ol(some special character) World" in my device.But the expected result is Olá World.Here á is been replaced with some special character.

Default encoding which Iam using is "iso-8859-1".Please some one help to resolve this issues.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your encoding to `UTF-8`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using encoding ANSI should solve the problem.

For example, actual spanish message:

> No importa cuántos planes de hacer o cuánto control usted es, la vida
>   siempre está improvisando

Your property should specify like:

> No importa cuÃ¡ntos planes de hacer o cuÃ¡nto control usted es, la
>   vida siempre estÃ¡ improvisando

How to convert from the former to the latter using any text editor, e.g. Notepad++:

1. Open new file
2. Copy the paste the string which you want to convert to ANSI.
3. Click Encoding & do convert to ANSI encoding.[if your default is UTF8]. If not toggle you should see what I mean.